# golang.org/x/tools/gopls gives not a valid zip file

Tags: go

I'm using golang version go1.17.3 linux/amd64 and when I try to install golang.org/x/tools/gopls using this command (as per the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/gopls#readme-installation)):

```
GO111MODULE=on go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
```

I get this error:

```
verifying golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.7.3: zip: not a valid zip file
```

Any help with this error?

Comment: I don't think it's your main problem, but the currently [documented](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#modules) way to install go modules is with the `install` command: `go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest`.

Comment: I tried that too. It seems my problem was not only with gopls but with any module that was already installed in the previous installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems the problem happens when you copy your mod folder from an older installation. The solution is:

```
go clean -modcache
```

This will clear your mod cache and allow installation to work again.